# If condition being ignored

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm currently writing code for a game called Caladont.
The game is about first player saying the word and the next one has to say the word that starts with last two letters of previous word.
The problem comes when I want to check if word contains less than 3 letters or if it's empty.

In the first cycle when list for filling is still empty, everything is fine.
However, after I type for example 5 or more words and type a single letter or leave it empty, it prints two `"You've lost!"` messages, which means that code from if statement is being ignored since it changes bool variable to false and is supposed to exit the While loop.

I've tried replacing `ok = false` with `Exit While` in condition which checks if words contains less than 3 letters and it worked, but I want to understand what is the problem.

The code can also be found here [Caladont game

- GitHub](https://github.com/whistleblower91/VB.net/blob/master/Caladont%20game):

```vb
Module Module1
   Sub Main()
       Kaladont()
   End Sub

   Sub Kaladont()
       Const msg As String = "You've lost!" 
       Dim list As New List(Of String)
       Dim word As String
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim ok As Boolean
       ok = True
       While ok
           Console.Write("Insert word:")
           word = Console.ReadLine()
           list.Add(word)
           If word.Length < 3 Or word = "" Then
               Console.WriteLine(msg)
               ok = False
           End If
           If list.Count > 1 Then 'Skip checking first word
               For i = 0 To list.Count - 2
                   If word.ToLower = lista(i).ToLower Then
                       Console.WriteLine(msg)
                       ok = False
                   End If
               Next
               If LastTwo(word) = "ka" Or LastTwo(word)="nt" Then
                   Console.WriteLine("KALADONT! You won!")
                   ok = False
               End If 
               If FirstTwo(list.Last) <> LastTwo(list(list.Count - 2)) Then
                   Console.WriteLine(msg)
                   ok = False
               End If
           End If
       End While
       Check()
   End Sub

   Function FirstTwo(ByVal s1 As String) As String
       Return Left(s1.ToLower, 2)
   End Function

   Function LastTwo(ByVal s2 As String) As String
       Return Right(s2.ToLower, 2)
   End Function

   Sub Check()
       Dim sign As Char
       Console.WriteLine("Do you want to start new game? y\n")
       sign = Console.ReadLine()
       If sign = CChar("y") Then
           Console.Clear()
           Kaladont()
       ElseIf sign = CChar("n") Then
           Exit Sub
       End If
   End Sub
End Module
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You have to post code here, not a link (or a picture) to it.

Comment: If you want to exit the loop when a certain condition is met then you have the statement Exit While. Setting the boolean variable  _ok_ to false doesn't prevent the loop to continue until you reach the End While and so the other test are performed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you set ok to false, it will still go inside the other loop, you'll need to use Else

```
        If word.Length < 3 Or word = "" Then
            Console.WriteLine(msg)
            ok = False
        Else If list.Count > 1 Then 'Skip checking first word
```

An other way would be to exit the while with End while.

```
        If word.Length < 3 Or word = "" Then
            Console.WriteLine(msg)
            ok = False
            Exit While
        End If
```